Using var inside try-catch block in Typescript
In my typescript project I am trying to fetch a user from database. Since it is possible that the specific user will not be found, I want to wrap the call inside a try-catch block:
try {
    const currentUser = await User.findOrFail(ctx.params.id)
} catch (e) {
    return ctx.response.status(409).json({ error: 'User not found' })
}

However, since I need the user outside the try-catch block, this code will raise an error (currentUser is not defined):
try {
    const currentUser = await User.findOrFail(ctx.params.id)
} catch (e) {
    return ctx.response.status(409).json({ error: 'User not found' })
}

  :
  : 

return { user: currentUser }

I want to keep the try-catch block wrapping only the fetch call (since later i might have other exceptions).
I understand that using var is not recommended (see JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example), however I don't see another clean way to implement what I want (const or let both don't work)
Ideas?

Declare the variable outside of the try block? So const currentUser; try { currentUser = ... }

You can't use const like that @Ivar.....

@Ivar, const variable cannot have their initial value changed.

Oh right, of course. But let should work that way. Both const and let are block-scoped, so if you declare them inside the try block, you can't access them outside. If you declare the variable outside of the try, you should be able to assign a value to it (if you use let) and it will be accessible further down, as long as it is still in the same scope (i.e. the return isn't outside of the block that the try-catch is in).
